# How can I set the default filename for a NAV report

Tags: dynamics-nav-2013

When I call REPORT.RUNMODAL(ReportID, xx, xx); If the user goes to print to PDF, they get this extremely useless default filename based on the report ID.

Is there a property of the report, or some property I can set in code so that this value will be something that makes sense, like the sales order number, or invoice number etc?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set a default name for the report go to ***report properties*** and set a ***caption or captionML*** (multiple languages). If report not have this property when you save in PDF NAV show then name of the report.